# what is to count second-degree followers for each followee?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand what is second-degree followers means?
I have a table following with two columns: followee and followers

```
Followee Follower
A        B
B        C
B        D
B        E
A        F
F        G
F        H
B        H
```

what is to find out second degree followers?

Comment: B follows A and C follows B thus C is a second degree follower of A. Example: `C > B > A`. D is also a follower of B and thus also a second degree follower of A, as is E, G, and H. So A has 5 second degree followers (C,D,E,G,H). **This smells like homework**

Comment: Thanks I got it..

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, you can see this with a self join.

```
declare @table table(Followee char(1), Follower char(1))
insert into @table
values
('A','B'),
('B','C'),
('B','D'),
('B','E'),
('A','F'),
('F','G'),
('F','H'),
('B','H')

select 
    l.Followee
    ,f.Follower as SecondDegreeFollower
    ,count(*) as CT
from
    @table l
left join
    @table f on f.Followee = l.Follower
where
    f.Follower is not null
group by
    l.Followee
    ,f.Follower
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----------+----------------------+----+
| Followee | SecondDegreeFollower | CT |
+----------+----------------------+----+
| A        | C                    |  1 |
| A        | D                    |  1 |
| A        | E                    |  1 |
| A        | G                    |  1 |
| A        | H                    |  2 |
+----------+----------------------+----+
```